# UIImage is not positioning correctly in Static Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a Static Table with 3 cells. I randomly put some label and other controller in each cell and run it. It shows fine. But when ever I put an image it cover up two or sometimes 3 cells at a time. In `UITableViewController` I comment all the `tableView` method. Why this is happening?

Comment: "when ever I put an image" - but how do you do that? Obviously the way you're doing it is wrong. But you are not _showing_ what you're doing, so how can anyone "understand" it?

Comment: Pease share some code so we can help you. If you are designing your cells using storyboards or XIBs, post some screenshots of it, too.

Comment: Drag and drop. No code. No CGRect. I don't now is it the right way or not? :-/

Comment: Do you have constraints set in XIB ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

1. It sounds like you are using static cells with `UITableViewDelegate` methods from your description, this does not add up. You don't need to implement those methods for a static table view.
2. Check your cell height and whether or not you have `clipsToBounds` enabled.
3. Check your `UIImageView` size and whether or not you have `clipsToBounds` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ((indexPath.row)==0)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"one"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-cover-image.jpg"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==1)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"two"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==2)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"three"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sectionHeader2.png"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }
    if ((indexPath.row)==3)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"four"];

        UIImageView *backgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 170)];
        backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-cover-image.jpg"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backgroundView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

If I simply just drop an `imageView` inside a Static Table Cell and add image in it, then the positioning didn't act accurately. Though the difference only appear in real device. Not in story board.
Thanks every one for commenting on my post. Have a good day. :)